# How do I display only one table of results only, results that are bound from an arraylist of objects to datagrid?

Tags: c#, arraylist, datagrid

I have a `foreach` loop that creates a new object call Time from the collections `TimeEntriesCollection`. After the loop, the object will be added into the `ArrayList` called `entryList`.

This `ArrayList` is passed through a method to the `DataGrid` to display the results, which show separate tables for different user, and that means separate headers too. How do I show all the objects in one single table without repeated headers?

Below shows the codes for the aspx page.

```
<asp:DataList ID="UserDetails" runat="server" Width="100%" OnSelectedIndexChanged="UserDetails_SelectedIndexChanged">
 <ItemTemplate>
  <asp:DataGrid ID="TimeEntryGrid" DataSource='<%# ListTimeEntry(TTSecurity.GetUserID(), _userIDs, _startDate, _endDate) %>'runat="server" BorderStyle="None" Width="100%" CellPadding="4" AutoGenerateColumns="False"Font-Name="Verdana" AllowSorting="True" BorderColor="White" OnSortCommand="TimeEntryGrid_Sort">
   <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" CssClass="report-header"></HeaderStyle>
   <ItemStyle CssClass="report-text" />
   <Columns>
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="UserName" HeaderText="Resource" SortExpression="UserName"ItemStyle-Wrap="false" />
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="EntryDate" HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="EntryDate"DataFormatString="{0:yyyy-MM-dd}" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" />
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="ProjectName" HeaderText="Project" SortExpression="ProjectName"ItemStyle-Wrap="false" />
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="CategoryShortName" HeaderText="Category" SortExpression="CategoryName"ItemStyle-Wrap="false" />
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="CompanyName" HeaderText="Company" SortExpression="CompanyName"ItemStyle-Wrap="false" />
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Duration" HeaderText="Hrs" SortExpression="Duration"DataFormatString="{0:n1}" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Cost" HeaderText="Charges($)" SortExpression="Cost" DataFormatString="{0:n2}"ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Description" />
   </Columns>
  </asp:DataGrid>
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

EDITED:

The `DataList` is used to get the 2nd parameter for the `DataSource` of the `DataGrid`. The original param was `(int)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "UserID")`, and I thought that it would mean getting only 1 user, so I replaced it with `_userIDs`(which is a string of integers with commas that will be processed in a stored procedure). But if I remove `DataList` tag and replace the 2nd param with `_userIDs` , nothing appears at all. With the `DataList` tag still there, the output I got is what I've stated at the top.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `DataList`? If you assign the `entryList` as the DataSource of the `DataGrid` then why is there a `DataList` around it?

Comment: The 'DataList' was used to get a single userID '(int)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "UserID")'. I try changing it to _userIDs (which selects more than 1 user through a stored procedure) and it produces the result that I want, but repeated for as many users as I had selected. It won't work without the 'DataList' which is binded with another 'ArrayList' used to show another table for the summary details. This table supposing will show a table of all the users, in further details.

Comment: I think you have managed to get yourself into a lot of unnecessary complexity. If you remove the DataList and assign the `entryList` to the `DataGrid` it will produce the 1 table of many users that you are after. I don't think your requirement justifies a nested repeater. You now repeat over the users and for every user you repeat over a collection of 1 entry in entryList hence 1 table per user, where just having the `DataGrid` repeat over the `entryList` would produce 1 table in total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have made a nested repeater where you are after a single repeater that produces one table. Consider the following set-up:

ASPX:
I removed some attributes to improve legibility

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="TimeEntryGrid" runat="server">
 <Columns>
  <asp:BoundColumn DataField="UserName" HeaderText="Resource" SortExpression="UserName"ItemStyle-Wrap="false" />
  <asp:BoundColumn DataField="EntryDate" HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="EntryDate"DataFormatString="{0:yyyy-MM-dd}" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" />
  <asp:BoundColumn DataField="ProjectName" HeaderText="Project" SortExpression="ProjectName"ItemStyle-Wrap="false" />
  <asp:BoundColumn DataField="CategoryShortName" HeaderText="Category" SortExpression="CategoryName"ItemStyle-Wrap="false" />
  <asp:BoundColumn DataField="CompanyName" HeaderText="Company" SortExpression="CompanyName"ItemStyle-Wrap="false" />
  <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Duration" HeaderText="Hrs" SortExpression="Duration"DataFormatString="{0:n1}" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />
  <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Cost" HeaderText="Charges($)" SortExpression="Cost" DataFormatString="{0:n2}"ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />
  <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Description" />
 </Columns>
</asp:DataGrid>
```

CS (Code behind):

```
ArrayList entryList = new ArrayList();
/* assign values to entryList here */

TimeEntryGrid.DataSource = entryList;
```

Comment: Wow, it never occur to me that way! Thanks so much, it worked. Have been stuck on this for awhile. Sorry for being ignorant about stuff like that!

Comment: Good to hear that you managed to find the solution and that I managed to help you in the right direction. This site exists exactly for that purpose so well done to the both of us! hahaha :)